# How to make Inception V3 model defined with slim do prediction on GPU

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, imagenet

I use the Inception V3 model defined by the slim to predict my own images. The model variables are restored from a checkpoint file. When I run it, I find that GPU is not used. I have set `tf.device('/gpu:0')`, but it does not work. So, I am confused that why training/retraining the model can work on GPU, but evaluating can not? I just follow the code in inception_eval.py.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fOmr.png)

Comment: What is the error when you speficy a gpu device?

Comment: @Fake: No error returns and the program runs normally. Maybe the model variables restored from the checkpoint file are resided on CPU? I paste my code in new comment.

Comment: Then how do you know it ignores the your specification for gpu devices?

Comment: I have checked my gpu condition via the command of "nvidia-smi", and found that it does not work.

Comment: When you create a session, does it print information about GPUs?